# Slack slash command getting 400_client_error from lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, slack, slack-api

I was hosting a simple slack slash command on heroku which worked fine. I moved it to lambda, but now it is getting:

`` Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `400_client_error`). Manage the command at . ``

The error doesn't provide more information and doesn't say what failed.

I can hit the endpoint with curl and it returns what looks to me like correctly formatted json:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://5hi90e8v8e.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: eacb33ee-96ac-457e-a325-9fdc132f808e' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

```
{
    "text": "Have suggestions to improve this bot? Message <@UC8R7PA87>",
    "response_type": "in_channel"
}
```

Headers:

```
Date →Sat, 09 Mar 2019 01:12:02 GMT
Content-Type →application/json
Content-Length →922
Connection →keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId →57cec19a-4208-11e9-924c-89367de80c6d
x-amz-apigw-id →WP_jLFWYiYcFiXg=
X-Amzn-Trace-Id →Root=1-5c8312e1-327ac177db85f799dcd267c1;Sampled=0
```

The response from my old heroku endpoint:

```
{
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "text": "Have suggestions to improve this bot? Message <@UC8R7PA87>"
}
```

Headers:

```
Connection →keep-alive
Server →gunicorn/19.6.0
Date →Sat, 09 Mar 2019 01:01:36 GMT
Content-Type →application/json
Content-Length →946
Via →1.1 vegur
```

Any ideas on how to find the actual error / how to debug?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Easy solution would be to use *API Gateway Lambda Proxy Integrations*, which moves the heavy lifting from the API Gateway to the Lambda function: [Understand API Gateway Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy)

---

**Lambda** is always going to expect to receive data from an **API Gateway** as `JSON`, and there are cases where the data being sent to the API isn’t `JSON`. 
That’s the case with **slash commands** coming from **Slack**. 
They make `POST` requests with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type, so the body of the request looks something like:

```
token=gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO&command=/weather&text=lorem
```

In **API Gateway**, the **Mapping Templates** section of the **Integration Request**, you have to add a template for the Content-Type of the request we are expecting. In this case it’s `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can simply wrap the request body as-is in a `JSON` object, so that we can get the value to Lambda for parsing.

```
{
  "postBody" : $input.json("$")
}
```

This info was taken from https://medium.com/@farski/learn-aws-api-gateway-with-the-slack-police-ca8d636e9fc0

Answer (score 1):

Probably, problem in AWS Gateway and how it transform request. Try to use:

```
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }
}
```

in Integration Request/Mapping Templates/application/json for debug.