# Slack Slash Command and API Gateway Integration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-commands

I have set up a Slack slash command which triggers an API Gateway which in turn execute my AWS Lambda.

The slash command works for now, but I am not able to retrieve the event in my AWS lambda.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073094/slack-slash-command-getting-400-client-error-from-lambda) on how to integrate my API gateway to accept non-json payload from slash command but now when i am sending a slash command such as `/helloworld trigger` the event of the AWS lambda is returned as such:

```
{'postBody': 'token=CGH9VQ5Gop...&team_id=...&team_domain=...&channel_id=...&channel_name=...&user_id=U01R5QXP61Z&...}
```

This is the code of my AWS Lambda as simple as that:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return str(event)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: There are two ways a lambda can be connected to your API - either by Proxy or by Integration - which are you using?  Are their any cloud watch logs of your lambda getting invoked? Try adding a logging statement so that Cloudwatch can catch it

Also, you what happens if you use the API Test feature on your Methods/Resources in API Gateway? Does it give an error? Returning a str to API req specific set up in the API with integration and method responses. You usually have to return a json with statusCode and body keys.

Comment: I am using Integration method. In the API test feature, the response body is `{}`. This is the same case with postman. Only slack slash command returns the response body i put in the question above. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, using an Integration Method you have a bunch of additional information coming - All the JSON information from the API gateway, plus all json information from the slack webhook. Given what I see in your response, it looks like channel information and such from Slack is being returned.

Since what you seem to want to return is just whatever you put in `trigger` then you would need to know what Key that is under in the json the slack webhook is sending.

If you cant find the schema of that json in the Slack API documentation, then you can just log the event and check it out in cloudwatch to see what the heck is showing up. You can then manipulate that json just like you would any json object in code and get the various keys you want out of it.

Comment: From what i understand from this link: https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling
Slack can't send json payload. It sends it in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` That's why i can't format the payload properly.

Comment: well the event being returned is clearly a json with a bunch of parameters. you might have to parse the parameters or something. Either way, putting the event into the log will show you what you're recieving and what to do about it.